# 1052: Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous when

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables which share a user id, now I want to get data from all 3 but I don't know where I'm doing it wrong in this query

```
SELECT user_id, first_name, image_id, description, gender 
FROM users a 
JOIN user_services b ON b.user_id = a.user_id 
JOIN user_timeframe c ON c.user_id = a.user_id
```

Comment: You must qualify all the selected columns with the table's name or alias

Comment: @forpas "must" should be "should" [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134008/5070879):)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I know, I know, I know but *must* comes earlier and easier to mind (why?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two key best practices:

- Always qualify *all* column references.
- Use table aliases that are meaningful rather than arbitrary letters.

So:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name, ?.image_id, ?.description, 
       u.gender 
FROM users u JOIN
     user_services us
     ON us.user_id = u.user_id JOIN
     user_timeframe ut
     ON ut.user_id = u.user_id;
```

The `?` is because it is not clear what table those columns come from.  (The other columns are guesses so they might not be right either.)

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way should be explicit aliasing. There is another way to fix this query by using `JOIN ... USING` syntax:

```
SELECT user_id, first_name, image_id, description, gender 
FROM users a 
JOIN user_services b USING(user_id)
JOIN user_timeframe c USING(user_id);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=292c216bbc135223fc2ee21612819d43)**